# AS3 Things moving randomly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am still a beginner to as3 but this is just crazy. when I spawn 3 movieclips and make them move it also moves the Background, Floor and Score the same direction and repeats it.

I think its a getChildAt error I have no idea what to do with.

```
//Spawn Pipes
    private function eSpawn()
    {
        for(var i:int = 0; i < ePipeMax; i++)
        {
            var _Pipe:EPipe = new EPipe;

            _Pipe.x = (i * 350) + 500;
            _Pipe.y = Math.random() * 250;

            stage.addChild(_Pipe);

        }
    }

private function _MoveStage():void
    {

        //Pipes Move
        for (var i:int; i < vPipeMax; i++)
        {
            var _Pipe = stage.getChildAt(i);

            if(_Pipe.x <= 238)
            {
                Score++;
                Scores.text = Score.toString();
            }

            if(_Pipe.x <= 0)
            {
                _Pipe.x = 640 + 100;
                _Pipe.y = Math.random()*100;
            }

            _Pipe.x -= xSpeed;
            trace("PIPES");
        }

    }
```

This is just a clipit of the full code but the error I found out is in the "var _Pipe = stage.getChildAt(i);" Because when I turn that off it fixes it but dosent move what I want to be moved.

also everything is on one layer... should I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Background, Floor , Score and your Pipes are all DisplayObject, that gets added to the stage. It doesn't matter it is added by codes or your paste the sprites on the stage in your IDE.

```
var _Pipe = stage.getChildAt(i); //this line gets the child object of the stage, based on an index
```

so it'll get the child objects, depending on the sequence of which they're added, up to a number of vPipeMax.

You could: add a layer that solely dedicated for pipes, called the pipeLayer, and iterate

```
var pipeLayer:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); //AS3 does not recognizes layer, here's a way to do that.
stage.add(pipeLayer);
```

`stage.getChildByName("pipeLayer").getChildAt(i)`

or

store the pipes in a global variable upon declaration as an array and iterate through them.

```
//Spawn Pipes
var Pipes:Array = {};
    private function eSpawn()
    {
        for(var i:int = 0; i < ePipeMax; i++)
        {
            var _Pipe:EPipe = new EPipe;
            _Pipes.push(_Pipe);
            _Pipe.x = (i * 350) + 500;
            _Pipe.y = Math.random() * 250;

            stage.addChild(_Pipe);

        }
    }

private function _MoveStage():void
    {

        //Pipes Move
        for (var i:int; i < Pipes.length; i++)//iterate through _Pipes
        {
            var _Pipe = Pipes[i];

            if(_Pipe.x <= 238)
            {
                Score++;
                Scores.text = Score.toString();
            }

            if(_Pipe.x <= 0)
            {
                _Pipe.x = 640 + 100;
                _Pipe.y = Math.random()*100;
            }

            _Pipe.x -= xSpeed;
            trace("PIPES");
        }

    }
```

Also, it's always a good practice to separate your sprites in different layers.

Comment: Could you give me the code to help me with the different layer part because I put "var _Pipe = stage.getChildByName("Pipes").getChildAt(i);" and its not working.

It would help out alot and thank you for helping me its a major learning curve for me.

Comment: @user3697993 layers does not exist in AS3, however you can do this-see edits. You can only add layers in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Mc Kevin's answer covers my first thoughts on the problem and as he points out, an array or vector solves the problem. I also think that by layers, Mc Kevin means new DisplayObjects (correct me if I am wrong Mc Kevin). It would work something like this.

```
// Inside of your main class or stage builder where you are currently creating pipes put...

// Sprite that will hold all of your pipe instances.
var pipes_layer:Sprite = new Sprite();

// Add your pipe instances.
for(var i:uint = 0; i < ePipeMax; i++){

    var _Pipe:EPipe = new EPipe;

    _Pipe.x = (i * 350) + 500;
    _Pipe.y = Math.random() * 250;

    // Instead of adding directly to the stage,
    // add pipes to the pipes_layer.
    pipes_layer.addChild(_Pipe);
}

// Finally add the pipes_layer to the stage.
stage.addChild(pipes_layer);
```

Then to access and move the pipe instances use something like this:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < pipes_layer.numChildren; i++) {
    // Move pipes. Access each pipe instance with
    // pipes_layer.childAt(i) (ex. pipes_layer.childAt(i).x = 5;)
}
```